# Regex AND operator for overlapping matches

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have two strings that are varying lengths of my name

```
chriscattano
```

```
christiancattano
```

I have substrings in lengths of 3 through 10 that both strings share

```
(chr)(hri)(ris)(cat)(att)(tta)(tan)(ano)(chri)(hris)(catt)(atta)(ttan)(tano)(chris)(catta)(attan)(ttano)(cattan)(attano)(cattano)
```

I am trying to put these into a regex search that will successfully match the words `chris` and `cattano` so that I can do a `.replace`, and apply a `<span>` with a sass class to the match's results.

If I format my regex to be:

```
/(chr)|(hri)|(ris)|(cat)|(att)|(tta)|(tan)|(ano)|(chri)|(hris)|(catt)|(atta)|(ttan)|(tano)|(chris)|(catta)|(attan)|(ttano)|(cattan)|(attano)|(cattano)/g
```

I manage to mutually match on `chr` and `cattan`, but I cannot figure out how to highlight `chris` and `cattano`; I'm missing the `is` and the `o`.

This example can change drastically as I am only using my name to test and perfect the functionality. It will eventually be used on email addresses, names, and addresses. So changing the order of the capture groups (if that could fix this) is not a solution and when it made to be more dynamic I will have little control over the order of the captures groups when they're put into a regex object, and fed as a parameter to the `.replace()` method.

Here is a regexpal where I've been trying various things to get it to highlight the matches I need. Hopefully someone might be able to tinker it into working?

http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=97413

Comment: What is your end goal? Are you trying to write code that will highlight the commons substrings of two strings? I have a feeling regular expressions are not the right solution here.

Comment: @Jordan Yes, when given two strings I have code that extracts all shared substrings between the lengths of 3 and 10. The idea was those substrings would then be passed to a regex object ad used as a parameter in a .replace() method. The .replace() method would replace the matched words with a span containing a sass class that specifies a background color. It would look something similar to h.replace(regexObj, `<span class="dedupe-match">${regexObj}</span>`);

Comment: Does order matter? What would `chriscattano` and `cattanoXYZchris` yield? There's [a lot of existing work](https://www.google.com/search?q=algorithm+find+all+common+substrings) in enumerating common substrings. Do you have a compelling reasons to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: You need to sort the groups by length in descending order. You may do it programmatically. Then just put them into a quantified group, `(cattano|chris|...)+`.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew! Flipping the order around highlighted exactly what I needed to have matches of! Why is it that searching for the largest matches first fixed my problem?

Comment: That is because in an NFA regex like JS or most others the first alternative found makes the regex engine stop processing the group, a match is returned. DFA returns the longest alternative match, but it is not the case with JS regex engine.

Comment: I see, it seems like I have some additional reading to do on the subject as my regex skills are very limited. Thank you so much for helping me with my problem, you've saved me from quite the headache!

Comment: I am not quite sure what output you need. Say, for `chriscattano`, what is the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort the items in your array by length in the descending order to make sure the longest alternatives are  tested first, and then join them into a pattern with `.join("|")`.

That is because in an NFA regex like JS or most others the first alternative found makes the regex engine stop processing the group. You may read more about it in [Remember That The Regex Engine Is Eager](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html#eager).